# Java double precision math

Tags: java, double

I'm doing a bit of modding to a popular game (Minecraft) and I seen these lines in the terrain generation,

```
double d4 = 1.0D;
d4 *= d4; 
d4 *= d4;
d4 = 1.0D - d4;
double d5 = (noise1[l1] + 256D) / 512D;
d5 *= d4;
```

I was wondering what the point of `d4` was, because on the fourth line it would always be 0, wouldn't it?

Comment: @pst: No, `1.0d * 1.0d` *is exactly* 1.0d, as 1.0d is exactly representable in binary floating point. (Compare that with 0.1d, which *isn't* exactly representable.)

Comment: @pst: why would 1.0*1.0 be anything other than 1.0 in floating-point maths?

Comment: According to this code yes and d5 will also be zero.

Comment: Have no idea where it was used, but to me it seems, that d4 could be some graphic parameter. 2nd and 3rd line are responsible for making a^4. Forth is negation of this value. If d4 would be set to something like 0.9 - the result looks quite ok.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, in straight Java at least this would be guaranteed to be 0.

For all the inaccuracies of floating binary point arithmetic, 1.0 itself can be represented exactly, and the result of multiplying it by itself will always get back to simply 1.0.

Are you sure there's nothing else going on elsewhere to make it *slightly* different to 1.0d? Or perhaps it was historically some value other than 0.1?